# Ember coffeescript @ inside a function on object is window instead of object

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, scope, this

I can't seem to reference the parent onject inside of a function defined on a property.

```
SocketMixin = Ember.Mixin.create

  thing: (->
    'dougs'
  ).property()

  getThing: ->
    console.log @ # window object
    @get('thing') # Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 

  sameWithFatArrow: =>
    console.log @ # window object
    @get('thing') # Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 

  printThing: ->
    @get('getThing')() # call the above function
```

There is no problem in computed properties

```
  thingProp: (->
    @get('thing')
  ).property()
```

works just fine.

I've been trying to get around the problem by passing @ around in the params but I'm pretty sure there must be a better way of calling these functions than this.

```
  getThing: (self) ->
    console.log @ # window object
    self.get('thing') # Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 

  printThing: ->
    @get('getThing')(@) # call the above function
```

Really, all I want to do is call a method.  It should be way more strait forward than all of this right!?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the function in the scope of the window.  Don't use the getter and just call the func. Getters and setters are only necessary when dealing with properties.  Functions are still called in the same fashion.

```
printThing: ->
    @getThing() # call the above function
```